# How to select all data from these two tables?

Tags: mysql

[Order Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28YKn.png)

[Product Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z3z3z.png)

I need to select all from these two tables. Is it possible?

Comment: Google: `SQL Joins`

Answer (score -2):

With the following query you can select all data from one table:

```
SELECT * FROM Order;
```

If you want to select all data from two tables you can use a join in the select query to connect the data of the two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Order
JOIN Product ON  Order.p_id = Product.p_id;
```

There are different kinds of joins available. Based on the one you use can change the amount of data you will receive. The different kinds of joins are:

> - (Inner) join: Returns records that have matching values in both tables
> - Left (Outer) join: Return all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table
> - Right (outer) join: Return all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table
> - Full (outer) join: Return all records when there is a match in either left or right table

The information about the different kinds of joins comes from the following website:https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp